# Arrays in JavaScript - sorting text and numbers in Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to populate 2 arrays that I have which are called 'regions' and 'asbos'. I want to do this using a list of the following data of ASBOs record in each Criminal Justice System area:

```
Avon and Somerset    559,
Bedfordshire         220,
Cambridgeshire       285,
Cheshire             387,
Cleveland            489,
Cumbria              275,
Derbyshire           319, 
Devon and Cornwall   473,
Dorset               197,
Essex                361,
```

I also wanted to create a `loop` for each region, giving it a particular `font size` that depends on the number of ASBOs and then store that formatted text in the 'tempText variable' as follows:

```
tempText += "<span style='font-size:" + asbos[i]/14 + "px';>" + regions[i] + "</span> ";
```

This is what I have so far in my `HTML` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Javascript_Arrays</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="wordCloud"></div>

      <script>
         //asbo word Cloud Generator
         var regions = [];
         var asbos = [];
         var tempText = "";

         // add loop here to create text for printing
         document.getElementById("wordCloud").innerHTML = tempText;
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Javascript is not the best language for reading in huge amounts of data: where is the data coming from, and are you using Windows™ or Linux ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var $body         = $('body'),
    regions_asbos = $('#inputs').text().split(/,\s*/gm), // <== 1
    asbos         = {};                                  // <== 2

regions_asbos.forEach(function(line){                    // <== 3
  asbos[ line.replace(/(\d+)/,'').trim() ] = RegExp.$1;  // <== 4
});

var regions = Object.keys(asbos);                        // <== 5
regions.forEach(function(region){                        // <== 6
  if (!region)                                           // <== 7
    return;

  var $span = $('<span></span>',{                        // <== 8
    'style': 'font-size: ' + asbos[region]/14 + 'px',
    'text':  region
  });
  
  $body.append($span);                                   // <== 9
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Inputs</h4>
<pre id="inputs">Avon and Somerset    559,
Bedfordshire         220,
Cambridgeshire       285,
Cheshire             387,
Cleveland            489,
Cumbria              275,
Derbyshire           319, 
Devon and Cornwall   473,
Dorset               197,
Essex                361,
</pre>
```

1. Get the text of your input (I put it in a pre) and split them up into an array, treating a comma and any whitespace (newline,etc) as a delimiter; this creates an array for each line or region/asbos association
2. Create a placeholder object; instead of having two separate arrays, all you need is one object that acts as a dictionary/hash
3. Iterate over each line
4. Use regex to capture the numbers (held in `RegExp.$1`) of the line (assuming your regions don't have numbers in their name) and replace those numbers with a blank string; this leaves the line with only the region name and a bunch of white text.  You can then trim off the whitespace and use the region name as the key of your dictionary/hash/object and assign it that number value you captured earlier.
5. You can use the `Object.keys()` class function to get all the user-defined properties of your object and store it in an array (this is your regions).
6. You can then iterate over your array of regions
7. If the line didn't have a region (it's null, undefined, etc.; often related to having a trailing comma)
8. Create the span (or whatever element) that you will post on the page; notice the use of `asbos[region]`, where *region* is a variable (one of the regions of your input)
9. Put that value some place on the page; in this case, at the end of the body

Answer (score 0):

First split the given text with `,` (comma & space together)

Then use the following regex to separate each member of this splitted array into two arrays; `/([\w\s]+\w)\s+([\d]+)/` first capture will be for region, and second capture for the ASBO array.

I hope this will be helpful.

```
var str = "Avon and Somerset 559, Bedfordshire 220"
var splitArr = str.split(", ");
for (var i = 0; i < splitArr.length; i++) {
   var matched = splitArr[i].match(/([\w\s]+\w)\s+([\d]+)/);
   region.push(matched[1]);
   asbo.push(matched[2]);
}
```

will result in;

```
region = {"Avon and Somerset", "Bedfordshire"}
asbo = {"559", "220"}
```

Comment: Avoid using [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) on arrays, please. You're teaching bad practices.

Comment: @Oka yeah sorry about it, just found out about it. Was using Java for a while, so used to for..in

Comment: @Oka, is this case, why are for..in loop so bad? According to documentation: "for...in should not be used to iterate over an Array where the index order is important." and the index is not important here, or is it?

Comment: @developer033 If the data is pre-sorted, and expected as such, then it could be an issue. Also, it iterates on _all enumerable properties_ - including those in the prototype chain. So, if someone includes [a lazy prototype shim](https://jsfiddle.net/znv58b08/), you'll get that as well. In general, `for...in` on arrays is just a bad practice - one that can be avoided by teaching the right way to do things - by using a regular `for` loop, `Array.prototype.forEach`, or even `for...of` in ES6.